# Connect to a server behind a server that is password protected jsch

Tags: java, testing, ssh, automation, jsch

I'm using jsch to connect to a server once I've connected to this(which I can do successfully) I want to connect to another server with a password. I know there is an example here http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ViaHTTP.java.html but it does not include a password prompt. Does anyone have any example or can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Here is an example of my usual steps execute when using putty.

1. type user name and password into putty.
2. Connect to the server I wish to use with ssh john@192.168.3.001.
3. Run command.

What I'm wondering what should I do to execute step 2. I can execute step 1 and 3 right now

Comment: Do you need anything beyond a swing popup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099371/creating-a-custom-blocking-java-swing-prompt

Comment: What is "another server with a password"?

Comment: I've updated my question which might give a better indication what I'm trying to do

Comment: Ok, so that another server is SSH, right? Not HTTP. So the `ViaHTTP.java` example is irrelevant to your problem, correct?

Comment: SSH is what is needed